# Image obstructing my navigation bar and the image above. Basic HTML/CSS issue

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image on my site that I want to be set as it's own entity that I can freeform and adjust without it conflicting with other elements, I have it's CSS as

```
#backgroundImage{
position:absolute;
float:right;    
top:0;
left:50%;
}
```

Using fixed and absolute positions cause the image to stack level to the Nav bar, but any other position will cause the Nav bar to jump right under the image I'm using (it's a picture of the moon) It is cutting off the image, text, but it's behind the Nav bar.

Things I have tried: Putting it inside of a  I have no idea how that would work out, and I tried floating it contained inside of a div.

I have also read some comments about putting it on the z or y axis, but I have no idea what that means, I'm still reading about it or trying to find something to help me understand it.

This is for a school project, I am still very basic in this field.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `z-index` of `-1`:

```
#backgroundImage {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Also, it's not recommended that you name elements with camel-case - use dashes instead.

Comment: I'm curious: Why is it not recommended to use camel-case?

Comment: that's an ID for an element, I thought we were supposed to use camel-case?

Comment: Nope. Not to my knowledge: http://csswizardry.com/2010/12/css-camel-case-seriously-sucks/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll use that from now on. My teachers might not like it because they taught me to use camelcase, but this page provides strong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element completely on it's own try using the  element from html. However, then it won't necessarily stay in the background. Hopefully this is what you were looking for

Comment: What do you mean? Please try to explain it in more details.